# Giving a salary manager free paid vacation?

Tags: vacation

I feel like I have been treated unfairly. I am the assistant GM at a chain restaurant. The GM was having a bad time and couldn't get their act together. They refused to take a leave of absence. The manager above us decided to give the GM a free 7 days off that were paid and not logged in our system, so it wouldn't take away from their vacation time.

This does not seem right to me, and when I was a GM struggling it was never offered to me. I feel like this was not ran by higher up managers in our corporate office.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Wgy " They refused"? More than one of them?

Comment: I think this is the new gender neutral they

Comment: Maybe your boss thought you were a stronger GM and didn't need the hand holding. Maybe your boss saw that you struggled and then another one struggled and decided to start offering it moving forward... it's just so hard to say. I do strongly suggest that you don't mention it as that will make things worse. Unless a history of making you out to be the "black sheep" happens I would let it go.

Comment: Rollback - Original question must remain intact.  This is not a discussion board.

Answer (score 7):

It's not really your place to question the decision made by your bosses boss. You should not let this worry you and just concentrate on your own tasks.

I can't see any way that making a fuss over this will benefit you, in fact it could make things unpleasant for you.

Life is often unfair or perceived as such and you don't know all the details that led to the decision.

Answer (score 1):

[@Joe Strazzere](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/giving-a-salary-manager-free-paid-vacation#comment164882_62000) and [@Killsi](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/62010/437) are wrong. You have every reason to question your boss' decision to grant extra paid vacation to your GM, because you need to know if you're in a "squeaky wheel gets the grease" situation where complaining is rewarded.

On the other hand, you need to realize that sometimes superstar employees have special status and can acquire special benefits without "warning". You probably don't know your GM's salary and you wouldn't know if he/she got a sudden pay increase or off-cycle bonus. Although vacation time is typically standardized among all employees with the same start date, it's really just another form of compensation. And when seen in that light, you can view this sudden additional vacation time award simply as **additional** compensation. Perhaps you should say to yourself, "Wow. He/she must be really special." And then resolve to be so outstanding at your job so that your manager notices. Soon, you may be eligible for extra and off-cycle compensation.